# Inserting big csv,xls data files into Mysql with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This code only works fine with csv file containing around 1K records. But it hungs if I try to insert files with let's say 100K.
I searched online and found many suggestions, like adjust php time-out of execution, increase memory allocated for php ( this helped a little), but I need to import large data files like 1 million records.

I'm using codeigniter.
Is there a way to speed up this process:
Description about this function:
- The first "INSERT INTO" inserts into table="client" the logged-in client(admin_id) and time-created(create_time).

-The second "INSERT INTO" inserts into table="client_attribute_value"  the attribute_id,client_id, and value.

```
    function Add_multiple_users($values)
{
    $err = '';
    foreach($values as $rows)
    {
        $clientQuery = 'INSERT INTO
                            client
                            (
                                admin_id,
                                create_time
                            )
                            VALUES
                            (
                                "'.$this -> session -> userdata('user_id').'",
                                "'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'"
                            )';
        $clientResult = @$this -> db -> query($clientQuery);
        if($clientResult)
        {
            $client_id = $this -> db -> insert_id();
            foreach($rows as $row)
            {
                $attrQuery = 'INSERT INTO
                                    client_attribute_value
                                    (
                                        attribute_id,
                                        client_id,
                                        value
                                    )
                                    VALUES
                                    (
                                        "'.$row['attribute_id'].'",
                                        "'.$client_id.'",
                                        "'.addslashes(trim($row['value'])).'"
                                    )';
                $attrResult = @$this -> db -> query($attrQuery);
                if(!$attrResult)
                {
                    $err .= '<p class="box error">Could not add attribute for<br>
                            Attribute ID: '.$row['attribute_id'].'<br>
                            Client ID: '.$client_id.'<br>
                            Attribute Value: '.trim($row['value']).'</p>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $err;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with this before.
[How to parse Large CSV file without timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11800101/how-to-parse-large-csv-file-without-timing-out)

Upload the file itself or find the location of the file and use a cron job to handle it. No timing out. The way I did it personally was set a queue system with a database table that pointed to the file and had a status flag. Once the cron job picked up that item it would begin inserting the CSV file (end of the day it was ~300mb in size). Once the cron job was done inserting into the db, it would delete the csv file, update the status for that queued item, and email me saying it was completed.

Comment: Is the a way I can incorporate " LOAD DATA INFILE " in this function?